# How can I make Azure function in one region communicate with Virtual Machine sitting on other region?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-network, vnet

I have resources spread across multiple regions (Central US and Europe) in `Azure` environment.

- Function 1 - Central US
- Function 2 - Europe
- Virtual Network and Virtual Machine - Europe

[image]

I am able to connect `function 2` and `virtual machine` using feature called `VNET integration` as mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet

But, I am not able to connect `function1` to `virtual machine` because these are cross region connection.

How can I solve this issue?  Do I need to add `VNET` in `central US`, then do VNET Peering?

Even though VNET-VNET (Virtual Network Gateway) connection established. I am using the premium azure function.
Unable to find the VNET belongs to another region in the dropdown :(

[image]

**Solution Found**

[image]

Comment: Do you deploy another VPN gateway in the region central us?  If so, do you try to enable function1 with vnet integration in the same region?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled it and now I am able to communicate. Issue resolved. Detailed step I will share as answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In order for function app to communicate with Virtual machine privately, function app needs to be integrated with VNET to be able to reach VM.
- The function app running on Elastic premium plan that only gives a single option of VNET integration which is Regional VNET integration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options#matrix-of-networking-features
- Function should be into **App Service Plan** (Dedicated Plan). Function app is having full access to **Point-to-Site VPN** connection and Regional VNET integration. I was using **Consumption plan** and which is also one of the issues.

Comment: Could you provide more details about your solutions? I guess, in this case, you have function1 in the region Central US and VNet in Europe then you deploy VPN gateway in the VNet in Europe, then you enable that gateway-enabled VNet integration with function1. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, I will update the end to end flow points, meanwhile, I have updated the diagram